How to prevent gtm sensetive data sending?
I`ve got Nuxt 2 + nuxt-gtm and there is a problem
I`ve got oauth2 scheme of auth and when login user returning to /callback page with query like code=some_code&state=some_state
How to prevent sending it?
I have no idea. I did all what i found in the internet. Nothing work.
I tried to write proxy and replace the sensetive data, but it sending...
When i returning from another domain the fist page is /callback?code=...&state=...
I realized that url saving in window.Navigation object
And it always send.
